# Pass dynamically constructed object as a parameter to JS function with Rhino

Tags: java, rhino

I hope it's a simple question but I cannot find an answer. I use Map as a way to pass parameters to the function in Nashorn. How could I pass dynamically constructed object as a function parameter in Rhino? Cannot find it anywhere. Example would be just great. I need to pass something like that:

```
{
   field1: "value1",
   field2: 2,
   someotherField: "another"
}
```

etc but created dynamically in runtime. I need to pass it to the compiled js function, like that:

```
String src="function fooname(params) {\n"+
                    "   for(var key in params)\n" +
                    "   {\n" +
                    "     print(key+\" : \"+params[key])\n" +
                    "   }\n" +    
                    "}\n";
Context context = Context.enter();
Script script = context.compileString(src, "testSource", 0, null);
script.exec(context, scope);
Function foo = (Function) scope.get("fooName", scope);
foo.call(context, scope, scope, params);
```

I need to assign to these "params" (for example to the params[0]) a dynamically created js object.

Comment: Why are you using Rhino? Isn't that older than Nashorn? Also, isn't what you have valid javascript so you could just execute it?

Comment: @matt Why?
0) Rhino 1.7.12 gbrail released this on 13 Jan · 1 commit to master since this release
1) JEP 335
That's why ;)
Didn't get your question about valid javascript

Comment: Hmm, is Rhino coming back? I'm going to miss Nashorn. Anyways, can you include a litlte bit of code to explain what your trying to do from the java end/ javascript end. If I run that through the script interpreter, x = {...} then I get a javascript object. I expect it will work with Rhino, Nashorn, firefox etc.

Comment: Dunno, I suppose it was still alive all these years, we just missed that. What code? I need it for any code, don't understand your question.

Comment: @matt Added some simple sample. Still don't understand how could it help

Comment: Have you tried the same thing except for your object string? Script.compileString(src2, ...); ? Where src2 assigns your javascript object?

Comment: @matt Sorry, don't understand

Comment: @matt I edited my question as you requested. Maybe now it's clear

Answer (score 0):

The `Context` class has some great options for this. Here is an example where I used two different methods to accomplish to create a function.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String funCode = "function(arg){ print(arg);}";
        String funName = "checkPlease";
        String objCode = "x = { one : 1, two : \"two\"};";
        Context context = Context.enter();
        Scriptable scope = context.initStandardObjects();
        context.evaluateString(scope, "function print( arg ){Packages.java.lang.System.out.println( arg );};", null, 1, null);
        context.evaluateString(scope, "print(\"to here\")", null, 1, null);

        Function fun = context.compileFunction( scope, funCode, funName, 1, null);
        Script s = context.compileString(objCode, "NA", 1, null);
        Object obj = s.exec(context, scope);
        fun.call(context, scope, fun, new Object[]{ obj});
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("this", "that");
        fun.call(context, scope, fun, new Object[]{ context.javaToJS(map, scope) });
    }
```

Since `print` didn't come in my scope I just created a function using evaluate string. I also created a function using compileFunction. I called the function and passed an argument three different ways. A) just calling the javascript function from javascript. B) Compiling a String and passing it as an argument, C) using context.javaToJS. This is the output.

> to here
>   [object Object]
>   {this=that}

Comment: Thank you! Well, the problem is, that I need it sandboxed and functions are created by end-users. I found similar in the runScript2 example, tried it and found that it exposes all java methods to the js script, along with parameter itself. I tried Context.javaToJs for a map like in your example and then I can call, for example, Object#getClass in my js. Is there a way to pass without ancestors fields/methods? Like nashorn, that passes just a Map content?

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase that - in this case arg is a java object, not a js object. For example, I cannot do let a=arg['this']; so it's not what I asked about

Comment: What about the other version, with the x={...} I checked and you can access x.one so I assume it is a normal javascript object?

Comment: Yes, second is better suits my needs, but i suppose that performance will be awful. I need this to process a large amount of data (really large, several billions per day) so stringbuilding these classes instances would be a horror

Comment: What are you starting with? This is getting a bit more involved. There is the security manager (that is null in my example ) that might let you sandbox better. There are also other tools for creating json, like jackson which could be more performant.

Comment: Yes, I didn't know it's important, now I see it is. JSon does not matter really. I call precompiled foo multiple times, and in this case I will need to recompile it on each iteration.